# How many devices can be simultaneously logged in under a single account? Is there a limit?

Tags: login, access

I recently came across a situation where a single account is to be given to a client in order to access a SharePoint site, however it is likely multiple people will use the same account.

That begs the questions, is there a limit for simultaneous access on a single user account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must confess is the 1st time i've heard that same account is used by the multiple people (except for Administratrive accounts) also because I'm not sure Microsoft would be happy with this model due to the CALs implications, not to mention the fact that this defeats the whole purpose of data security, permissions and overall you loose any sense of tracking of data managed in SharePoint.

Without going further into that topic, there is NO actual limit into how many simultaneous login-s of the same account are performed, but again, if you experience weird behaviors while editing one page, check in/out documents, etc. then you should think about that 1st hand.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and you definitely bring up some good point with security and tracking. In my situation this would not be wide scale, just one or two people, but the question still jumped out at me since I had no clue what to think about it.

Comment: As far as the licensing issues, the internet connector license should take care of those concerns.  I've never heard of multiple people using the same account for internal purposes because everyone in the company has a domain account.  It's usually for external facing SharePoint sites which this occurs and this is also where the internet connector license comes into play.